# Version control of business objects

Tags: php, object, version-control, rdbms

Is there a recognised pattern that addresses being able to "version" business objects in a web application, persisted in a RDBMS?

As an example if an audit log from a web application read thus:

```
2011-08-20 14:05:00 User A added changed setting "A" of object "B" to "3" 
2011-08-20 14:04:00 User A added changed setting "B" of object "B" to "2"
2011-08-20 14:01:00 User A added changed setting "C" of object "B" to "1"
```

How would one architect a system to allow the user of the application to "roll back" the state of object "B" to that before 2011-08-20 14:01:00?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on Doctrine 1.2 [Versionable](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/behaviors/en#core-behaviors%3aversionable) behaviour.

Sad thing is that behaviors are discarded in Doctrine2. But there are a [tutorial](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-versionable) on how to implement it yourself.